# Java Swing How to get child node row index with respect to other child node

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, jtree, treenode

I have below Tree structure which is sub class of JTree

[image]

When the user selects a node, **Time** in image above, I need to get the **Row index** (index value = **3**) of **Demoscrigo**(image above) with respect to **Wells** not from actual **Root**. Same index will be used to pre-select the row in other UI.
I can get the selected Object but as the nodes has duplicate entries that is making things difficult.
I have tried below options

```
    getRowForPath(new TreePath(selectedNode.getPath()))
    getSelectionRows()
    
    this.getModel().getIndexOfChild(userObj, selectedNode);
    JavaClientTreeModel treeModel = (JavaClientTreeModel) this.getModel();
    selectedNode.getLevel()
    
    this.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    this.getLeadSelectionRow();
```

But not able to figure out any specific combination. Please suggest me if any other solution is there.

Comment: If you're using multiple DefaultMutableTreeNodes to create the JTree, the getParent method gets the parent TreeNode.  Get the parent in a loop until you get to the node you're looking for.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

Comment: If you are not using `DefaultMutableTreeNodes` (most likely you are using them). Simp,y subtract the row of the "new root" from the row of the node.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have used getParent and with few modification, able to achieve row index. Adding my code below. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @weisj subtraction of row does not give proper result when other nodes are expanded.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the `node` for which Index need to be calculated by using the below code.
Parameter `Type` is used to get the above `node`

```
public DefaultMutableTreeNode findNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, String type){
        Object data = (XXXX) node.getUserObject();
        if(data.getType().equals(type)){
            return node;
        }else if(!node.isRoot()){
            return findNode((DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getParent(), type);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And then use

```
int rowIndex = node.getParent().getIndex(node);
```